# Winston logging bad json syntax

Tags: javascript, json, winston

I'm new to Winston and I've poorly coded a log system that uses json.
When I tried to open that output file as a json, Js gave me an error, then I went to the file and I saw that it isn't well formed, is there something I'm missing here?

#### This is my json log generated from Winston:

```
{
    "timestamp":"2019-01-11T17:59:47.847Z",
    "response":"",
    "level":"info",
    "message":"log 1"
}
{
    "timestamp":"2019-01-11T17:59:47.854Z",
    "response":"",
    "level":"info",
    "message":"log 2"
}
```

I understant it has to be comma-separated and with brackets, so what's wrong here? Why is Winston throwing multiple separated entries instead of a single json file?

Comment: This is actually pretty standard behavior for logging libraries.  It's much faster to append to a file without regard for correctness across the entire file, which would significantly increase the complexity of the logger.

Comment: @Amy ok, so how do I open it on Js and extract data from entries? I tried JSON.parse(thisFile) but it doesn't find a json.

Comment: Use a JSON log viewer made for that purpose.  Google "json log viewer github" and you'll find some free ones.

Comment: Thanks, it is useful, but I need to read the values from code, they're not for me, I just want to test the log.

Comment: You could write a script that reads line by line and concatenates them until it gets to a line with just `}`, then calls `JSON.parse()` on that string to parse it.